# Custom url for primary action button

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I'm trying to create a plugin through jackhenry.dev. In the custom plugin, I want to open up the expanded view with different url than url given in Primary redirect URI. Document suggests that we should use jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge in order to use different url for expanded view.

I followed the instruction given in https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/ .

As per doc, I understood that we should add anchor link in the primary redirect page and framework bridge would redirect to that page which is pointed by the anchor link when user click on primary action button. But the plugin is not functioning as expected that action button still taking me to the primary redirect uri instead of new anchor link pointed page and I see anchor link in the plugin which is not suppose to show.

Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding on the relationship, which hopefully will make more sense with some clarification.

The [User Interface](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/#4-primary-action-optional) anatomy page for the *Plugin Framework* talks about the **primary action button** and how it shows up on the **Card Face** when configured. That anatomy page also mentions that the **[Plugin Bridge](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/)** is an alternative to using the **primary action button**. (It's certainly *possible* to use both, but is an unlikely combination in practice.)

The [Designing and Developing Plugins](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#activating-the-expanded-view-from-the-card-face) guide has more info about the tradeoffs involved when choosing between the **primary action button** and **Plugin Bridge** as options for activating the **Expanded View**.